# Boiling dish soap

Tags: everyday-chemistry, safety, food-chemistry

Is it dangerous to boil dish soap (natural, ex: walgreens brand "ology") while also cooking other foods in the kitchen (ex.pasta)?

I was trying to clean some pots and read online that a good way to clean them is to boil dish soap in them. I was also making dinner at the same time and I am worried that I released toxic chemicals into the air and into my food.

How hot does soap need to be heated to cause it to decompose, and what substances will be formed by the decomposition of the soap ?

Answer (score 3):

You probably don’t have to worry about toxic chemicals in the air/food. Most dish washing liquids/gels/soaps contain chemicals that can be tolerated fairly well.

Nevertheless, boiling dish soap in a pot can potentially generate harmful substances. This may happen when your dish soap is very concentrated (when nearly all water has evaporated) and the temperature in your pot may rise to a point at which the ingredients of your dish soap could decompose or generate noxious fumes. If you make sure that there is enough water in your point at any time, your maximum temperature should not go above the boiling point of water (100 °C / 212 °F) which should be fine for most detergents.

Answer (score -1):

No. This is ill-advised. Changes in heat generate chemical reactions. Raising the temperature of many chemicals can cause them to produce toxic gases or other substances. If you are not familiar with the way each chemical reacts to heat/other chemicals under heated conditions you risk producing many combinations of harmful substances. For instance, many chemicals in cigarettes are harmful and many are not nearly as harmful, but when heat is applied many non-harmful chemicals can produce dangerous carcinogens or even chemically react with the other chemical(because they are under circumstances they were not designed for).